# Finding MULTIPLE elements with no IDs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, css-selectors

So, my class in school likes to play kahoot, my teacher always gets frustrated when the students put bad words within their names. I am trying to build a google extension that will filter the names and remove the names that contain bad words. Anyways, in kahoot, they do not specify an id that I can use to identify elements to read and filter. Is there any way to get around this?

[Kahoot screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCB7b.jpg)

```
while (true) {
    var Name = document.getElementsByClassName('controller-entry__ControllerName-sc-sqj4to-1 onogI')[0];
    console.log(Name)
}
```

Comment: Try this selector: `main > section > ul > li > button > span`. But I'm not sure what you'd do with that...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @code, is there any way that I can put that into code, I don't know how should use the path you gave me, thank you

Comment: Good luck fighting an unwinable battle.

Comment: Use `[...document.querySelectorAll('...')]` to get an array of those elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (or `querySelectorAll`) to target elements using arbitrary css selections; this is useful in cases where elements haven't been assigned ids.

For example to find all elements without an `id` attribute you could do:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(':not([id])');
```

This doesn't directly answer your question; it's just an example. Without seeing the html it's hard to directly answer!